# Can't execute binding command

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a button like this:

```
<Button Content="Gönder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="932,23,0,0" Height="25" Command="{Binding Path=SetTeamList}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=UrlBox, Path=Text}"/>
```

And at the VM, i have a method

```
public void SetTeamList(string Url)
{
    //Some things here
}
```

The solution is WinForms app, so i set DataContext like this:

```
var view = new dTeamMapperForm();
view.DataContext = new TeamMappingVM();
elementHost1.Child = view;
```

Nothing happens when i click the button, no error or something. I put break point to SetTeamList method and it's not executing on button click.

Edit: I have changed the whole VM, now it looks like:

```
class TeamMappingVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Team> TeamList { get; set; }
        public ICommand SetTeamsCommand { get; internal set; }
        private string _url;

        public string Url
        {
            get { return _url; }
            set
            {
                _url = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Url");
            }
        }


        public void SetTeamList()
        {
            var mapper = new TeamMapper();
            TeamList = new ObservableCollection<Team>(mapper.MapTeams(Url));
        }

        public bool CanParseTeams()
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Url);
        }

        public TeamMappingVM()
        {
            SetTeamsCommand = new RelayCommand(SetTeamList, CanParseTeams);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your Method SetTeamList encapsulated in an ICommand implementation? Command Expects an Property of type ICommand.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: can you paste your command code

Comment: @Xeun i didn't know that. I added the ICommand but still nothing happens. Please see updated vm.

Comment: @kyle i have changed the vm and posted the whole code.

Comment: @deusExCore great! Now you just need to Bind to the Property SetTeamsCommand. Command="{Binding Path=SetTeamsCommand}". As I said you cannot bind to a method (at least not in your case :))

Comment: @Xeun right, i totaly forgot to change that. Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Command-Property of a Button expects you to Bind to an Property of type ICommand.

In your Case you tried to Bind to a method, which does not work.
Since you edited you post i will just post this as the answer:

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Gönder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="932,23,0,0" Height="25" Command="{Binding Path=SetTeamsCommand }" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=UrlBox, Path=Text}"/>


class TeamMappingVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Team> TeamList { get; set; }
    public ICommand SetTeamsCommand { get; internal set; }
    private string _url;

    public string Url
    {
        get { return _url; }
        set
        {
            _url = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Url");
        }
    }


    public void SetTeamList()
    {
        var mapper = new TeamMapper();
        TeamList = new ObservableCollection<Team>(mapper.MapTeams(Url));
    }

    public bool CanParseTeams()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Url);
    }

    public TeamMappingVM()
    {
        SetTeamsCommand = new RelayCommand(SetTeamList, CanParseTeams);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

As a minor side note. Which was not asked. Since you are probably Using Databinding for your URL Textbox you don't need to pass it into the method via CommandParameter, Since the URL Property of your ViewMOdel represents this textbox. You want to try to seperate the view from the logic. This is a very small issue and might not have any effect, but it sort of is a bad habit to fall into.

Answer (score 1):

As Xeun pointed out, a Command is not a method but an object implementing the ICommand interface. A Command implementation look like this:

```
class MyCommand: ICommand
{
  public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
  {
    return true; // if your command is "enabled" otherwhise return false
  }

  public void Execute(object parameter)
  {
    // do something usefull
  }
}
```

In this sample you should add an instance of MyCommand to your ViewModel an 
bind to it.

Please notice usually you dont code commands this way.

A command usually interact with your ViewModel (ie it invokes Model methods) and inside MyCommand you have not references to the ViewModel hosting it. 
(You could create a Command which hold a reference to its ViewModel, but...) Usually inside a ViewModel you use a [Relay command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) or a [Delegate command](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html) (which are basically the same thing).